# search box is not inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I don't know why the search box and button is not in line with the menu links.
I use bootstrap [3.3.4](http://%3Clink%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20href=%22https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css%22%3E)
I use span but it don't stay on the line with logo and menu links.
When I apply margin-top to the button it create space at the botton.
https://jsfiddle.net/MeycD/868/

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<a href= "#"class="navbar-brand"><span class="icon-bar"><img src="raiselogo.png"/> logo</span></a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
<span class="col-xs-7 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
<input type="search" id="q" class="form-control input-sm" name="q" placeholder="Enter Search Term" ></span>
<span class="col-xs-3 col-md-4 col-lg-4 "id="srchbtn"> 
   <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
 Search video
  </button>
</span>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">

    <li class="active "><a href="#">Home</a>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="logout.php">log out</a></li>
</ul>   
</div>
</div>
```

This is the style code:

```
  #q{
margin-top:5px;
 display: inline;
}

  #srchbtn{
 display: inline;margin-top:5px;

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `<span class="col-xs-7 col-md-5 col-lg-5">`

to

`<span class="col-xs-7 col-md-3 col-lg-3">`

Demo [Here](http://www.bootply.com/u6bX5VsRcJ)

Is it what you want?

Update: Its because of [Bootstrap Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why exactly this works? It's always better to learn things instead of copying code :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to place the search box and button to be placed in the header, it won't work this way since you are putting these elements outside the "navbar-header" div. Try to put these elements inside that div and hide them until you hit the menu button upon which a simple jQuery would show them up.

Check this jsFiddle for reference jsfiddle.net/ynh95c9k with slight changes in the CSS:

```
#q {display: inline;float: left; width: 200px; margin-top: 10px;}
#srchbtn{display: inline;float: left; margin-top: 10px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had tried like you before!! But this approach compromised me.Hope for you also.Navbar and form style conflict, here we can use `navbar-form` like follow:

```
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
      <li>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" method="GET" >
           <input type="search" id="q" class="form-control input-sm" name="q" placeholder="Enter Search Term" /> 
           <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> Search video</button>
        </form>
     </li>
     </ul>
```